# Boolean values: t vs. nil vs 1 vs -1

Tags: lisp, elisp

In Elisp, I've encountered different APIs for modeling boolean values.

I was under the impression that `t` and `nil` were the idiomatic ways of representing true and false respectively. However, I've also seen `1` and `-1` used to model the same thing.

What confuses me is that I have come across APIs that won't work if `nil` is supplied but will work if `-1` is used.

Can someone help me understand which is in fact the preferred way. And if the answer is `t` and `nil`, I welcome any theories on why some developers use `1` and `-1` for their APIs...

Comment: "I understand that 1 and -1 can be used in a truthy or falsey context to achieve the same effect" No, they can't. Both 1 and -1 are truthy. In fact everything except `nil` is truthy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

sds and sepp2k have covered the main misconception, but in answer to:

> why some developers use 1 and -1 for their APIs...

The reason that Emacs minor modes use positive and negative numbers (or rather non-positive numbers, including zero) to mean "enable" and "disable", rather than using `t` and `nil`, is that the argument is *optional*, and when an optional argument is not supplied its value will be `nil`.  Consequently it would not be possible to distinguish between passing an argument of `nil` explicitly, and not passing an argument at all.

Historically, passing no argument (i.e. an argument of `nil`) meant that the mode would be *toggled*.

These days the mode is only toggled when calling it interactively, and an argument of `nil` means "enable".  This change was made so that the likes of `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'some-minor-mode)` -- which will result in `some-minor-mode` being called with no arguments -- is guaranteed to *enable* that mode.

Comment: so minor-mode cannot be enabled or disabled by simplify set  `some mode   -1`?

Comment: @Alice, `(foo-mode 1)` *enables* the mode, and `(foo-mode -1)` *disables* the mode.  (Is that what you're asking?)

Comment: If you want to make non-interactive elisp code *toggle* a minor mode, you can pass the argument `'toggle` (which has slight benefits over establishing the current state of the mode and passing the inverse argument).

Comment: amazing, so do not have to modify other files excluding init.el

Answer (score 9):

## Lisp

In lisp (both Emacs Lisp and Common Lisp) the only false value is `nil`.
Everything else is true, including 0, -1 &c &c.

## Emacs

Emacs uses negative arguments (including -1) to indicate "turn off this mode". E.g., <kbd>C-h f toggle-truncate-lines</kbd>

> With prefix argument ARG, truncate long lines if ARG is positive,
>   otherwise fold them.